# How to solve this integral for three-point correlation function?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, integration

I need to solve the following integral as part of the computation of a three-point correlation function in a charged massless quantum field theory, where I can also assume conformal invariance.
$$
\begin{align}
    (\star)= \int\frac{d^{d}x}{(|x-x_a|^2|x-x_b||x-x_c|)^{d-2}}
\end{align}
$$
Using Feynman parameters, I arrive at the following form
$$
\begin{align}
(\star)= \frac{\Gamma(2d-4)}{\Gamma(d-2)(\Gamma(\frac{d-2}{2})^2)}&\int_{0}^{1}d{u_1}d{u_2}{u_1^{d-3}}{u_2}^{\frac{d-4}{2}}({1-u_1-u_2})^{\frac{d-4}{2}}
\\
\times&\int\frac{d^{d}x}{(u_1(x-x_a)^2+u_2(x-x_b)^2+(1-u_1-u_2)(x-x_c)^2)^{2d-4}} 
\end{align}
$$
and through Schwinger parameterization I arrive at
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
(\star)&=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{3d}{2}-4)}{\Gamma(d-2)(\Gamma(\frac{d-2}{2})^2)}\int_{0}^{1}d{u_1}d{u_2}{u_1^{d-3}}{u_2}^{\frac{d-4}{2}}({1-u_1-u_2})^{\frac{d-4}{2}}  
\\
&\times ({u_1}{u_2}(x_a-x_b)^2+{u_1}(1-u_1-u_2)(x_a-x_c)^2+{u_2}(1-u_1-u_2)(x_b-x_c)^2)^{4-\frac{3d}{2}},
\end{split}    
\end{align}
$$
which I have been unable to simplify. I was advised to use the result for the four-point integral $\int\frac{d^dx}{|x-x_1|^a|x-x_2|^b|x-x_3|^c|x-x_4|^d}$ and send one point to infinity but I haven't been able to find a simple reference for either this four-point integral or this procedure of sending points to infinity. Any tips or references welcome.

Comment: Is there a reason why one  of the $|\ldots|$ in the denominator of $(\star)$ is squared and the others are not?

Comment: @mikestone yes, in the full computation I have a sum of three integrals of this type (corresponding to each of the three points being the squared quantity)

Comment: Isn’t the result equal to zero due to the $\phi \rightarrow - \phi$ symmetry?

Comment: I have corrected my post where I mistakenly wrote that I'm working in $\lambda{\phi}^4$ theory, I am actually working in a theory with three complex fields $\phi_i$ which interact with each other by $\lambda\phi_{i}\overline{\phi_{i}}\phi_{j}\overline{\phi_{j}}$.

Comment: Have you checked in Gradshtein&Ryzhik?

Comment: Are you sure the integral is conformally invariant? Anyway, can you post the Schwinger parameterization? You should be able to do the $d^dx$ integral at least.

Comment: @and008 I have updated my question to include the Schwinger parametrization. I'm really not sure if the integral is conformally invariant but I had been advised that it might be related to a scalar conformal block so this is the direction I've been looking in.

Comment: Thanks, it looks indeed complicated. Another idea: three points define a plane, so you can split the integral into an orthogonal $(d-2)$-dim part and a parallel 2d part. The orthogonal part should be trivial, and integrals of this kind in 2d are well known, look e.g. for KLT integrals in string theory.